# Gitlab doesn't open Word files

Tags: gitlab

I'm uploading docx file in Gitlab, however it doesn't preview it.

It only downloads it.

Is it fixable?

Comment: Gitlab is an open source project so you're not stuck with what they've done. 
 You can make a patch yourself and try to get it added. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only view text/source code files, Markdown files and images.  Gitlab doesn't have a preview option for other files such as proprietary word processors.

Answer (score 4):

A word document is not a source document that is fit for version control, it's a proprietary binary file.

For version control, try to learn a real source document like e.g. Markdown or AsciiDoc. In this way you'll be able to preview in Gitlab or Github, even with Windows.

While still being able to publish it after rendering it with e.g. Pandoc to a .docx or .pdf, .html, RTF, ODT, EPUB or all of them with an optional version tag.

Answer (score 0):

DOCX actually is zip-archive which contains xml. Xml is text format which should be fine viewed and tracked by Gitlab and other version control systems. Unfortunately, now this feature is unavailable. But exists alternative path - use third-side utility Pandoc.

I found information about Pandoc at this link:
https://github.com/vigente/gerardus/wiki/Integrate-git-diffs-with-word-docx-files